# It's easy to track down the etymology of the verb to calve . What is the origin of glacial calving?

Tags: etymology

Is this term recent and is it supposed to parallel birthing a calf?

Comment: It's a [Metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf). It's old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Books searches do not turn up such early matches as those mentioned in Josh61's answer from Etymonline (1837 and 1818). The Google Books matches go back only to the 1850s. From Henry Cheever, [*The Whale and His Captors, or, The Whaleman's Adventures and the Whale's Biography*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QTYMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA202&dq=iceberg+calving&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF26az9uzOAhVEImMKHQYuAe0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=iceberg%20calving&f=false) (1851):

> One large American whaler, the Pacific, was lost in the year 1807, by mooring alongside of a lofty iceberg. Conscious of the danger, the seamen had taken the precaution to run out lines so as to ride at some distance from the ice. A boat was sent off with the mooring anchors, which are shaped like the letter S, and let into the ice by means of holes cut for them with a hatchet. On one of the seamen striking a projecting piece, a crackling noise was heard, and presently several large pieces, or ***calves***, as they are technically called, fell off into the sea. Such occurrences, however, are sufficiently common to excite no unusual surprise, though indicating the unsound state of the iceberg; but before the boat could row back to the ship, the entire mass, of probably many millions of tons of weight, gave way with a tremendous crash, flinging an immense crag from its summit right in the direction of the ship, which stove in its side. ... An equally sudden, but less fatal accident, occurred to the Thomas of Hull, in 1812, while lying moored to an iceberg in Davis' Straits [between Labrador and Greenland]. The more common mode of the iceberg ***calving***, as it is called in seaman's phrase, is by large masses tumbling from above; sometimes, however, they get detached at the base, by the grounding of the floating mass far beneath, and rise with great velocity to the surface. Such was the danger from which the crew of the Thomas narrowly escaped. A ***calf***, detached from beneath, rose with such tremendous force, that the keel of the ship was lifted on a level with the water at the bow, and the stern was nearly immersed beneath the surface. Fortunately the blow was received on the keel, and the ship was not materially damaged; but had it struck the side of the vessel, as in the previous case, it would probably have stove it in and sunk it.

From H. Rink, "[On the large Continental Ice of Greenland, and the Origin of the Icebergs in the Arctic Seas](https://books.google.com/books?id=wgQcAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA152&dq=iceberg+calving&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF26az9uzOAhVEImMKHQYuAe0Q6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=iceberg%20calving&f=false)," in *The Journal of the Royal Geographical Society of London* (May 9, 1853):

> In considering the manner in which the ice moves from the interior down into the ice-friths, and its breaking up there; and how the ***calving***, or liberation of the floating icebergs, is effected, the following special remarks may help to explain and illustrate the earlier views formed on the subject in different records of travels. ... In the meanwhile this weighty plane body [of glacial ice now submerged as it is pushed into the ice-frith] preserves its continuity in progressive motion over the old beach at the bottom of the sea unchanged as when on shore, till the outer end has reached a depth in which the water begins to bear it up, where, still preserving its connection [to the parent glacier], it proceeds, thus borne up by the sea, till some exterior cause makes the connection cease, when the outer end breaks off and becomes a floating iceberg. This action is called calving, and such is the concussion, that it sometimes sets the sea in motion to a distance of 16 miles. ... Continental ice, or gletchers, which are exposed to much action of the sea, produce only *small **ice-calves***, and no *icebergs*, or at best, of small size. It is uncertain whether the continental ice advances gradually and regularly, or periodically. Its breaking or **calving** is altogether independent of this, as it seems to depend on outward causes, in such wise that the station or limit, to which the outer end may attain, is uncertain, and may sometimes proceed much further without breaking than at other times; ...

And from John Towson, "[Icebergs in the Southern Ocean; A Paper Read before the Historic Society of Lancashire and Cheshire, on the 19th of November 1857](https://books.google.com/books?id=yjdWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=iceberg+calving&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF26az9uzOAhVEImMKHQYuAe0Q6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=iceberg%20calving&f=false)" (1859):

> Icebergs are not the produce of one season; on the contrary, there is reason to believe that these masses commenced their formation at a period equally remote with that of the origin of some of our tertiary rocks. They are of the same nature as the glaciers of the warmer regions of the earth; but instead of being melted in the valleys, they are pressed forward into the ocean till at length the water is sufficient to float them, and immense blocks are broken off. This process has been termed by the Greenland whale fishermen, the "**calving**" of an iceberg.

All three of these early examples involve whalers working in the vicinity of Greenland, so the attribution in Towson's 1857 paper of the term *calving* to "the Greenland whale fishermen" may be as reasonable a conjecture as we can hope for. I note that very young whales are also termed *calves*, as are very young walruses (when they aren't called *pups*). It may be that whalers were disposed to view the birth of something so large as an iceberg (or a large fragment from an iceberg) as being comparable to the birth of a baby whale, and to give it the same name.

Comment: "millions of tons of eight", "direction of the hip", looks like these are just some missing letters in the transcription?

Comment: @John: Yes those are instances of me fighting (and losing to) my keyboard in an ongoing effort to press all the keys correctly and not hit the wide spaces between the keys (which results in a persuasively loud tap sound but no letter). Thanks for pointing out the two errors, which I've now corrected.

Comment: Yeah, just trying to help. Thought at first an encoding translation problem for older typography. Alas, just a funny keyboard. Well done considering.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the the usage which refers to icebergs (to set loose a mass of ice) is an extension of the original to calve ( to give birth ):

[To calve](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=calve&allowed_in_frame=0) used to refer to ***[ice calving](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_calving)*** is from the first half of the 19th century:

> - Old English cealfian, from cealf "calf" (see calf (n.1)). ***Of icebergs, 1837***. (Etymonline)

***[Calf](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=calf&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - "young cow," Old English cealf (Anglian cælf) "young cow," from Proto-Germanic *kalbam (source also of Middle Dutch calf, Old Norse kalfr, German Kalb, Gothic kalbo), perhaps from PIE gelb(h)-, ***from root gel- "to swell," hence, "womb, fetus, young of an animal."***  Elliptical sense of "leather made from the skin of a calf" is from 1727. ***Used of icebergs that break off from glaciers from 1818.***.